# hyper-v virtual machine dynamic memory warning

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, virtual-memory

I have a virtual machine that uses dynamic memory in my hyper-v manager.

- startup memory: 1024 MB
- min: 1024 MB
- max: 4096

The memory demand (4300MB) of this vm is greater than the assigned memory (4096MB). It's a problem that is easily fixed. But the strange thing is, if I look into the task manager/resource monitor of the vm, it only uses about 40% of the 4096MB assigned. So why does it demand 4300MB?

Can't explain it and didn't find an answer online.

Comment: I encountered this recently, I had a machine demanding 164 TB! It has a max of 6gb of memory assigned to it, it was only using 5gb, with the top process using 2gb, SQL Server. The VM runs Windows Server 2012R2, with SCCM and SCOM as its primary usage.

Comment: 164 TB, that's crazy! You think it's a bug in the hyper V manager?

Comment: That was my thought. For what it's worth, I'm using 5Nine Manager for Hyper V.

Comment: What do you get if you run this command in a Powershell session on the Hyper-V Server?
get-vm  "vmname" | select name, @{name="Current Memory Demand (in GB)";Expression={$_.Memorydemand / 1gb -as [int]}}

Comment: Mine reads 6gb in Powershell but 164tb in the hyper-v manager.

Comment: Mmh, seems it's not a bug in v-manager. Excecuted the command and the vm is actually demanding 4382 MB...

Comment: Monitored the vm. There were a few peaks higher than 4GB. These peaks are to blame. But this doen't explain your problem with the 164 TB. But thank you for your help!

Comment: Yeah, that's probably about normal.